# Splitting a list into each unique element

Tags: list, python-3.x, split

I am attempting to create a program so that a user inputs a list of numbers and then series of lists/sublists which contain unique elements are returned.

Ex.
input[5,5,5,3,1,0] would return [ [0], [1], [3], [5,5,5] ] 
input [6,7,8] would return [ [6], [7], [8] ]

My approach was to create a function that would:
1. First sort numerically (I know that isn't necessary for the task)
2. I counted the number of times any number appears in the entire set.
3. I then counted the number of sub-lists or unique elements take place in a list.
4. I then attempted to use an for statement to slice but I got a 'list index out of range error' so I stopped trying with that.

I revised, and currently my code is
removed

---

I am trying to split A into Q lists, so that I can manipulate the lists to give me what I want (the element printed the number of times it originally appeared).

Sorry if this is a bit unclear, or I've provided unnecessary information. Ultimately I am looking for help splicing the list up to Q times in the form:
__
List[0]
List[1]
...
List[Q]
__

I got an error with the `for loop`. If there is another way to do it that way, I would appreciate guidance. If I am approaching this problem the wrong way, and there is a much simpler solution I'm open to hearing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with the `set()` object, just use it in a slightly different way.

```
def grouper(sequence):
    groups = []
    for i in set(sequence):
        groups.append([x for x in sequence if x == i])
    return groups

>>> grouper(range(6))
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> grouper([1, 1, 2, 3])
[[1, 1], [2], [3]]
>>> grouper([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3])
[[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4], [5]]
>>>
```

This of course assuming you can't use the `itertools` lib.

**EDIT:** Because I couldn't resist but try and turn it into a one-liner :P

```
result = [[x] * sequence.count(x) for x in set(sequence)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect. I'm going to read up more about sets.

Answer (score 1):

Too much work.

```
3>> [list(y) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted([5,5,5,3,1,0]))]
[[0], [1], [3], [5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have been tasked not to import modules like itertool (I should have mentioned that in the OP).